# In firebase can we control what to sync

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to have conditional sync in firebase where in during sync I need to have limited data for a user that is necessary for him. How it can be done.

Comment: Did you mean security rules?

Comment: Not security rule, I mean to say what could be workaround lets say every user has different dataset, which needs to be available to his own group and not to other group. The data should be limited, not the data from all user sets.

Comment: That's what security rules enforces.

Answer (score -1):

read this 
[link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)

> By enabling persistence, any data that the Firebase Realtime Database
>   client would sync while online persists to disk and is available
>   offline ...